# Editing related content in Zend 2 Forms

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am having an issue where I cannot save related content on an Edit form. Adding seems to work just fine yet both are using the same `Fieldset` and View file

It also seems I can remove elements from the collection but adding them seems to fail (the post data doesn't contain the data)

My view file :

[Edit.phtml](http://pastebin.com/6R0JJBbL)

Page Fieldset :

[Pagefieldset.php](http://pastebin.com/fnKmb9nE)

Block Fieldset :

[Blockfieldset.php](http://pastebin.com/VUR6Xn1K)

Add / Edit from controller:

[Controller.php](http://pastebin.com/cM8AtL76)

Bizarrely if I change my edit.phtml file to just output the whole form as a collection then the new entries are added to the collection

```
<?php
    $title = 'Edit Page';
    $this->headTitle($title);
?>
<h2><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h2>
<br>

<?php

    $page = $this->form->get('page');
    $form->setAttribute('action', $this->url(
        'admin/page',
        array(
            'action' => 'edit',
            'id'     => $this->id,
        )
    ));
    $this->form->prepare();
    // echo $this->formElement($this->form->get('csrf'));

    $this->form($this->form);

    echo $this->form()->openTag($this->form);
    echo $this->formCollection($this->form);

    echo $this->form()->closeTag();
?>
```

Comment: We would need your BlockFieldset :)

Comment: The BlockFieldset is fairly straight forward but I have updated my answer linking the file for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The markup in my edit.phtml was causing the form to close before the collection was being added which explains why the fields weren't in the post data.

Need to be more careful where I place `<?php echo $this->form()->openTag($this->form); ?>`

Simplified example of the issue

```
<div>
    <?php echo $this->form()->openTag($this->form); ?>
    <?php echo $this->formCollection($page->get('blocks')); ?>
</div>
<?php echo $this->form()->closeTag(); ?>
```

This caused the browser to add a close tag early within the div element

Correct output would be

```
<?php echo $this->form()->openTag($this->form); ?>
<div>   
    <?php echo $this->formCollection($page->get('blocks')); ?>
</div>
<?php echo $this->form()->closeTag(); ?>
```